# Links within lists are inheriting menu list properities?

Tags: html, css, list

Whenever I make a link within a list, it inherits the properties of the menu link list in my CSS. I pasted the CSS of the menu list below which keep on passing its properties to any links within any list in my website. I need help as to how can I label the menu list items in a way that they don’t pass their properties to any link in a list.... Please help!

```
ul li a {display: block;background: #660000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;color: #fff; border-left:1px solid #660000;}

ul li a:hover {background: #3300cc; margin: 0; }

li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute; margin:0; }

li:hover li {float: none; }

li:hover a {background: #3300cc;   }

li:hover li a:hover {background: #660000;   } 

.drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px; position: relative; padding:0px; z-index: 100; border-bottom:0px; margin: 0; right:0; left:0; }

li li:hover a {display: block;  } 

li li ul a {display: none; border-left:1px solid #660000; margin-left: 60px;  margin-top:-30px;  margin-bottom: 30px; } 

li:hover li:hover ul li a:hover {background: #660000;  margin-top:-30px;  margin-bottom:30px; margin-left: 60px;border-left:1px solid #660000; }
```

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use less general selectors in your Menu list like a *'.class'* instead of *'ul li'*.

OR

Use the pseudo *:not* on your anchor tags used in main area. *(Be careful it's not supported by every browser)*

Comment: How would you do that exactly?.. I get the idea, but I don't understand how you would implement it.

Comment: In your HTML use a class for example .meni-item on the anchor tags.

Than in the CSS instead of "ul li a" selector, use the one you just created now, like:

.menu-item {display: block;background: #660000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;color: #fff; border-left:1px solid #660000;}